# How can save some Objects, directly after the User has closed the Applications JFrame, but before the Program exits?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, windowlistener

Good day!

I'm developping a small Java Application with NetBeans IDE that extends JFrame. I implemented several ways to close the App, for example pressing *Ctrl-Q* and pressing the X of the JFrame.

But before the actual closing I'd like the program to execute some additional code for me, to save some objects the application needs to reuse the next time it starts up.

What is the best way to change the entire programs closing behavior?

I'm thinking about overriding/replacing the defaultCloseOperation, something like this:

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation( myOwnCloseOperation );
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `setDefaultCloseOperation( myOwnCloseOperation );`  (scratches head) What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Good question!That didn't work

Comment: Also there are no errors, because developping an Gui with NetBeans using the Design Window restricts direct access to this method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE )`
2. Add a `WindowListener` or `WindowAdapter` - overriding either the `windowClosing()` or `windowClosed()` methods (I forget which) to catch the closing event.
3. Call the save functionality from the window method.
4. Call `setVisible(false)` or `dispose()` (as discussed in the comments) at the end.

Comment: on `windowClosing()` to call `JFrame#setVisible(false)`

Comment: @mKorbel  `setVisible(false)` or `dispose()`?

Comment: right good question, for `JFrame` doesn't matter if you to call `setVisible(false)` or `dispose()`, for `Swing's Top-Level Containers` there isn't implemented the method `finalize()`(GC'ed), then this container in both cases waiting only for `System.exit(0)`, no changes for JVM memory, or... :-) +1 previously for faster answer

Comment: @B. Lauing and finally most important 5th. point, if everything ended, then you have call System.exit(0); otherwise current JVM instance never ended, stays in RAM, until PC switch off :-)

Comment: 1.
public void buildGui() { 
}
 
private void formWindowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
}

private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
}

private void myCloseOperation() {
setVisible(false);
System.exit(0);
}