# how to call a method before exit in jframe with java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

i tried like they answered in this question
[How can save some Objects, directly after the User has closed the Applications JFrame, but before the Program exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760876/how-can-save-some-objects-directly-after-the-user-has-closed-the-applications-j)
but the frame won't close

i wrote the following but it's the same thing, the frame wont close .

```
@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

    dispose();
    setVisible(false);
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    dispose();
    setVisible(false);
    System.exit(0);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add shutdown hook in general to do work just before the jvm exits, no need for these listeners.

[Shutdown Hook](http://www.iks.hs-merseburg.de/~uschroet/Literatur/Java_Lit/JAVA_Insel/javainsel_11_011.htm)

If you want to do it by listener, use the windowClosedEvent:

```
@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    save();
}
```

By default the last frame exits the application, unless you did not set the default close operation to anything other than DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.