# Calling function on windows close

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, windowlistener

Using Java: I have a GUI built using the netbeans GUI builder.

The GUI class was created by extending a jFrame

`public class ArduinoGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame`

and the GUI displayed using:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {                    
        new ArduinoGUI().setVisible(true);                    
    }
}
```

Therefore I don't have an actual frame object on which to call `frame.`, so how in this case can I override the `windowClosed` function, because I have to call a specific function to tidy up a serial connection before the app exits.

Edit: here is the code explicit as answered below:

```
@Override
public void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) {
    if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
        arduino.close();
        System.out.println("Arduino Close()");
        dispose();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can save some Objects, directly after the User has closed the Applications JFrame, but before the Program exits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760876/how-can-save-some-objects-directly-after-the-user-has-closed-the-applications-j)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create "processWindowEvent" method in your class (which is subclass of JFRame) if you haven't already done. That method takes WindowEvent object as parameter. inside that method add an if block like this :

```
if(e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING){

    //...Do what you need to do just before closing

}
```

e is the WindowEvent object passed parameter to method.

Comment: I added that, but now when I press the close button it will execute that code, but it no longer closes the program. You don't happen to know the exit program command ?

Answer (score 4):

You can call your function on windowClosing method..

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

class WindowEventHandler extends WindowAdapter {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("Call your method here"); 
  }
}

public class TJFrame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Frame");

    JTextBox label = new JLabel("This is a Swing frame", JLabel.CENTER);

    frame.add(label);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowEventHandler());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(350, 200); // width=350, height=200
    frame.setVisible(true); // Display the frame
  }

}
```