# Disable close button in Processing

Tags: java, awt, processing

Is there a way to disable the window's close button in Processing, during a certain event?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
  {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
      if (youWin == 0) // condition that is supposed to keep the application opened
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"You can't exit until you finish this game. OK?");
        // keep applet opened
      }
    }
  }
);
```

EDIT: I want to do it without using JFrames.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499211/calling-function-on-windows-close

Comment: River: it's an `awt.Frame`, like every usual Processing main frame.

Comment: Then you can use the above answer... It doesn't need to be a `JFrame` to use `WindowAdapter` or `WindowEvent`. (As *your* code above clearly shows.)

Comment: Yes, I know, but the thing is also about adding an `awt.Frame` equivalent of the JFrame method `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This answer is for Processing 2. It won't work with newer versions of Processing.

> I want to do it without using JFrames.

Too bad. You're already using a `JFrame`, you just don't know it.

Processing will create a `JFrame` for you, even though it's stored in a `Frame` variable. If you don't believe me, check out line 453 of [PSurfaceAWT](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PSurfaceAWT.java).

That means you can use `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` to tell the frame to, well, do nothing when you click the X button. This disables the low-level listeners that automatically close the JFrame.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
void setup() {
  ((JFrame)frame).setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

That's only half the battle though. Processing also has its own listener that detects when the user clicks the X button, on top of the low-level listener. This listener calls the `exit()` function, which closes the sketch anyway.

To get around *that*, you have to override the `exit()` function. (You could also remove the listener that Processing adds, but this is easier imho.)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
void setup() {
  ((JFrame)frame).setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
}
void exit() {
  println("not exiting");
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

Okay, we've completely removed the ability to close the frame with the X button. Now we have to add in the ability to close it when we want to. You can do this either by adding a call to `super.exit()` in the `exit()` function:

```
void exit() {
  if(reallyExit){
    super.exit();
  }
}
```

Calling `super.exit()` will close the sketch for you. It's up to you how you set the `reallyExit` variable.

Another approach would be to add a `WindowListner` to the `JFrame` that handles the closing event:

```
void setup() {

  ((JFrame)frame).setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent we) {
      if (reallyExit) {
        frame.dispose();
      }
    }
  }
  );
}
```

Here's a full example that uses both approaches. You only need *either* a call to `frame.dispose()` *or* a call to `super.exit()` though. It's really up to personal preference.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

void setup() {

  ((JFrame)frame).setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent we) {
      if (mouseX < 10) {
        frame.dispose();
      }
    }
  }
  );
}

void exit() {
  if(mouseX <10){
    super.exit();
  }
}


void draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```