# ClassCastException Processing.core

Tags: java, swing, awt, processing

I'm making a simple tool with Processing 3.

I want my sketch to not close when the "X" button is pressed. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789409/disable-close-button-in-processing) here on StackOverflow, but when I try doing that, I have this error: `ClassCastException: processing.core.PApplet$8 cannot be cast to javax.swing.JFrame`

I've tried adding more libraries, but now the error says is non a library error.

Here a piece of code:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  ((JFrame)frame).setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
}
void draw() {
  textSize(50);
  text("some text", width/2, height/2)
}
void exit() {
  println("Not exiting");
}
```

When I try to run the sketch I have the error `ClassCastException: processing.core.PApplet$8 cannot be cast to javax.swing.JFrame`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you linked to is for Processing 2, but you're using Processing 3.

Your error says it all: `frame` cannot be cast to `JFrame`, which is what you're trying to do here:

```
((JFrame)frame).setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

To understand the source of this error, you can look at the source for the `PApplet` class [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java).

Do a search for `"frame"` in that file to see that the `frame` variable is now a `java.awt.Frame` instead of a `javax.swing.JFrame`. Processing also overrides some of the functions in the `java.awt.Frame` to provide Processings-specific behavior and warning messages.

You could start researching how to prevent a `java.awt.Frame` from closing, but I'd also consider rethinking whether you want to do this at all. Preventing windows from closing is a bit of an anti-pattern, so you should think carefully about whether you really need to do this. You could also consider other options, such as using a full-screen window rather than an uncloseable one.